# Changing an object property from an object list - every object is getting the property changed

Tags: java

i have a list of objects:

```
List<TaskDataValue> configuredTaskData = sourceofdata;
```

I am iterating the list, to change a property from an object WITHIN the object:

```
for (int i=0; i<configuredTaskData.size(); i++) {
    FieldConfiguration fc = configuredTaskData.get(i).getSettings();
    String fieldName = configuredTaskData.get(i).getName();
    if (newLabels.containsKey(fieldName)) {
       fc.setLabel(newLabels.get(fieldName));
       configuredTaskData.get(i).setSettings(fc);
    }
}
```

although what is happening is that every TaskDataValue.getSettings.label is set to the last one,

sounds like `configuredTaskData.get(i).setSettings(fc);` is setting not only to `i` but to evry one

What can be happening here ?

using java 1.6

Comment: Post your `TaskDataValue` class. I bet that the settings field is `static`

Comment: nop m8 :) , here's the bit : `public class TaskDataValue {`
`...`
`private FieldConfiguration settings;`

Comment: And where do you create the `TaskDataValue`s in `sourceofdata`? Is it possible that they all have been configured with the same `FieldConfiguration` instance?

Comment: Is configuredTaskData.get(i).getName() returning the same value everytime? Did you check that?

Comment: @crnlx checkd, and nop, its always different

Comment: Ok. Hard to debug without the source. Does newLabels.get(fieldName) return different values everytime?

Comment: @crnlx yep, nothing wrong with the labels hashmap

Comment: @Mike B nop, a new instance of FieldConfiguration is being created for every one

Comment: How did you get "TaskDataValue.getSettings.label"? Did you write code or examine the object after the loop executed? Or did you mean you debugged and found that "configuredTaskData.get(i).setSettings(fc)" is setting it to the last one?

Comment: examined right after the loop, when i debug inside the loop, everything seems fine, `log.info("fieldName: "+fieldName+ "setting "+newLabels.get(fieldName));` before `fc.setLabel(newLabels.get(fieldName));` shows different and right every time

Comment: @Mike B you were correct, ill leave you some time if you want to write a question mentioning that so i can aprove, Thank you

Comment: @EnoqueDuarte I added an answer, I'm glad you were able to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check where you create the `TaskDataValues` in `sourceofdata`. Is it possible that they all have been configured with the same `FieldConfiguration` instance?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for something like this to happen is that you only actually have one `TaskDataValue` object - or inside `TaskDataValue` there is an object that there is only one of.

Because that object is shared any change made to it from one reference is also seen from all the other references.

For example:

```
List<TaskDataValue> tdvs =  ...;

TaskDataValue v = new TaskDataValue();
tdvs.add(v);
tdvs.add(v);
tdvs.add(v);
```

That code creates one single `TaskDataValue` object and adds three references to that object to the list. If you change a setting inside `tdvs.get(1)` you will also see 2 and 3 change too.

Comment: what if the block `TaskDataValue v = new TaskDataValue();
tdvs.add(v);` is inside a loop, wont it create different objects ?

Comment: Correct. If each time you add a v it is a new v then it will create different objects.